# React Native Windows Support to write Native Bridge

Tags: wpf, reactjs, react-native, react-native-windows

We recently completed app development for IOS and Android version using React Native.

Now, our client is asking for Windows version also.

Can anyone can answer following question, would really appreciate that:

1. Do we require Windows machine to develop and test RN windows app version or Mac also can support?
2. How to write a bridge to communicate with native environment (like to read/write files in the file system, etc...)
3. Any articles, learning materials would be really helpful.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it is also a very broad and is likely off topic for Stack Overflow.  I recommend doing some research and then asking a more specific question.